# Cómo puedo regresar a un estado antes de aplicar las migraciones por primera vez?

Tags: python, django

Tengo un problema con el Framework Django,
0) levanté mi proyecto django

1. cree varios modelos
2. ejecute python manage.py makemigrations
3. ejecute python manage.py migrate

Luego de hacer esto me di cuenta que no lo tenia que hacer,
ya que quiero un modelo personalizado para la logica de los usuarios de mi app,
Django me dice que para tener una modelo de usuario personalizado tengo que crear primero el modelo y luego aplicar las migraciones

## CustomUser

#### src.apps.account.models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField("email address", unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

## Settings

#### src.settings.base.py

```
# Tabla para autenticacion de usurios.
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "account.CustomUser"
```

No sé si me explique, es decir me salte este paso, ya que quiero cambiar el campo de login de username a email, así los usuarios podrán ingresar con su email.
la pregunta es
Cómo regreso a un estado antes de aplicar las migraciones por primera vez?

-Intente borrar la base de datos sqlite y los archivos de migración que se encuentran dentro de las apps pero cuando vuelvo  ejecutar makemigratations migrate, este se da cuenta de que existen migraciones anteriores

-Tambien intente con
python manage.py migrate nombreapp zero
pero restablece las migraciones al forma de cómo se ejecutaron la primera vez

Alguna solución?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente no estas borrando todos los archivos de las migraciones, dentro de la carpeta migrations de cada una de tus apps debes de borrar todos los archivos dentro de la carpeta migrations a excepción del archivo **init**.py, tienes que borrar los archivos con extensión .py y .pyc.

Si usas linux o tienes wsl dentro de la carpeta de tu proyecto puedes ejecutar este script para que te borre todas las migraciones:

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
```

Ya con esto deberia de ser suficiente para borrarlas

Posteriormente ejecutando

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Ya deberias de poder ver que se crean las nuevas migraciones y ejecutar el migrate te deberia de generar la base de datos nueva.

Tambien cerciórate que estés borrando la base de datos sqlite correcta, ve que el nombre y la ubicación del sqlite que estas borrando es el correcto, puedes ver la ubicación en tu settings en el apartado de DATABASES donde tengas el backend de sqlite. Si borras el archivo sqlite correcto de tu base, cuando corras el migrate te va a crear el nuevo archivo.

Cuando se da cuenta que existen migraciones anteriores es por que no se borro tu base y en la tabla django_migrations esta el registro de las migraciones que aplico